# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException when doing in query openJPA

Tags: jpa, jpql

Suppose I had a list of ID associated with an entity stored in a list.  If I pass this list into a function if I use the IN keyword in JPQL then I should get the same functionality as using in in reqular query language I am assuming...

But I am experiencing that exception whenever I attempt to run my code...  My code looks like this...

```
public void UpdateEntityByPerson(int ID, int[] EntityIDs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<EntityList> distList = null;//new ArrayList<EntityList>();
    try{        
        Provider prov = emf.find(Provider.class, new Long(ID));
        prov.setDistListPermCollection(null);
        distList = emf.createNamedQuery("getEntityListByListIds").setParameter("listIds", EntityIDs).getResultList();
        prov.setEntityListPermCollection(distList);         
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Exception : "+ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my JPQL named query...

```
@NamedQuery(name="getEntityistByListIds", query = "SELECT d FROM EntityList d WHERE d.listId in :listIds"),
```

What could I be doing wrong here?  One thing that I thought of is that I have an array of integers... The EntityIDs  are actually longs... that may be causing a slight brew-ha-ha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When type of listId attribute in EntityList is long, then type of parameter to IN must be single `Long` or `long` value or `List<Long>`. So in your following kind of arguments are applicable:

```
List<Long> EntityIDs = Arrays.asList(new Long[]{1L, 2L});
Long EntityIDs = 0;
long EntityIDs = 0;
```

In specification this is spelled in more general form as follows:

> The literal and/or input parameter values must be like the same
>   abstract schema type of the state_field_path_expression in type.
>
> Only the values of like types are permitted to be compared. A type is
>   like another type if they correspond to the same Java language type,
>   or if one is a primitive Java language type and the other is the
>   wrappered Java class type equivalent (e.g., int and Integer are like
>   types in this sense). There is one exception to this rule: it is valid
>   to compare numeric values for which the rules of numeric promotion
>   apply. Conditional expressions attempting to compare non-like type
>   values are disallowed except for this numeric case.

For me it looks that, according specification you could give also `int` parameter to IN when path points to long, but at least with Hibernate's implementation that is not the case.